# Ansible with host_key_checking set to false fails with "Host key verification failed."

Tags: ssh, ansible

In my `ansible.cfg` I have

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
```

Yet my ansible git play is dying on a `git clone --bare`.

> "msg": "Host key verification failed.\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This requires the special option in the [git module named `accept_hostkey`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/git_module.html).

- The option in the ansible.cfg controls whether or not the controller node requires a valid hostkey for connection.
- On the machine you're provisioning you must tell it too that it doesn't require a valid hostkey. You can do this by

  - setting an `~/.ssh/config` on the remote host with `StrictHostKeyChecking no`
  - or by setting an option in the module that is using ssh, telling it to disable host key checking

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use GIT_SSH_COMMAND

```
---
- name: Clone a Git repository with host key checking disabled
  hosts: your_target_host
  environment:
    GIT_SSH_COMMAND: 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'

 tasks:
    - name: Ensure the target directory exists
      file:
        path: /path/to/your/target_directory
        state: directory

    - name: Clone the Git repository with host key checking disabled
      git:
        repo: https://github.com/example/repo.git   
        dest: /path/to/your/target_directory
```